# configuring elasticsearch in 2.4.0

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I installed magento 2.4.0 on sheared hosting with 1 click installation.

I understand that Magento 2.4.0 needs Elasticsearch to operate properly and I have set up an instance with AWS and I'm now trying and failing to configure my magento installation to connect to it.

I've entered the credentials into the back end but I'm still getting an error message about no active nodes on my cluster

Comment: did you start elasticsearch ? check if it's running on your server or not

Comment: yes it was fine, I've created a second deployment at elasticcloud and I've entered the details in the back end but I'm still getting an error message about no active nodes

Comment: yes I check it is

Answer (score 0):

Use port `443` and make sure you don't have a trailing slash on the hostname.

This fails: `https://vpc-domain-name-identifier.region.es.amazonaws.com/`

This succeeds: `https://vpc-domain-name-identifier.region.es.amazonaws.com`